# Symfony variable does not exist

Tags: symfony, twig, entity

I want to display a welcome message for an appointment when the startdate is near (the function is built with js). 
Now for the view: The data that is in the message comes from another entity which is related to by use of a join-column. Now i cant use a loop through the appointments because this wil show the message for all the appointments regardless of what the startdate is.

this is is my appointment entity

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="appointments")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\AppointmentRepository") */    

class Appointment
{

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $client;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="ClientEmployee")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="appointment_clientemployee",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="appointment_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="cascade")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="clientempoloyee_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="cascade")}
 *      )
 */
protected $clientEmployees;
```

This is my client entity

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="client")
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
*/
class Client
{
   /**
  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="ClientEmployee", cascade={"remove", "persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="client_client_employee",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_employee_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true, onDelete="cascade")}
 *      )
 */
protected $clientEmployees;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="path", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $path;
```

This is the HTML(im using twig templating)

```
<div class="message-overlay">
    <div class="message-box">
        <p>Van harte welkom</p><br>
        <p> {{  appointment.client_client_employee.firstname }}</p>
        <div class="greeting-box" style="background-image: url({{ asset('bundles/app/img/dots-repeat.png') }});">
            <img class="message-embleem" src="{{ asset('bundles/app/img/Lameco_Icon_1.png') }}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="image-box">
            {#<img src="{{ asset('/../../../../web/' ~ client.path) }}"/>#}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know that clientemployees is an array so i have to build a forloop around it, but i need to get inside the appointment first.

Comment: Its unclear, what exactly do you want ? You want database query that will select appointments, that are about to start ? If yes, you need to post complete entities ... i dont see start date attribute anywhere

Comment: Well i allready have a query that selects new appointments in the database and i use javascript and ajax to show them. And i have a div with a welcomingmessage and it shows when the startDate of any appointment is within 5 minutes of the current time (I compare startdate and current date using js). But now i want to display the information about that specific appointment (client, description etc.) in that welcomingdiv. But i cant acces the data in the html. I hope this is clear enough..

Comment: you need to access client employees with {{ appoitment.clientEmployees }}, try this: {{ dump(appointment.clientEmployees) }}

Comment: I get the error "Variable "appointment" does not exist in AppBundle..."

Comment: did you export variable `appointment` ? can you post your controller ? i suggest you go over chapter http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html to make sure you understand how templates work